# Will OpenLayers 4 change its v3 api?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am developing a big software using OpenLayers 2.13.1. I am estimating migrating the software to 3.8.2 version, but it seems that version 4 is right around the corner, and i am concerned if it will change all api again.

Does anybody know about it?

Comment: "Around the corner?" https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/milestones

Comment: When i say this i mean, "next to"... seems that version 4 could being released soon. But is just a guess, because of the version number (3.8)

Comment: Also discussed here :-( https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4020

Answer (score 1):

The following links document changes:

- https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/v4.0.0.md
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229046/openlayers-4-differences-from-3-x

Answer (score 0):

There is no plans for a version 4 (major revision with breaking changes) of OpenLayers.

Major version 3 
Minor version 8 (There was 8 release with new features)
Revision version 2 (Bug Fixes)

After 8 comes 9,10,11,12,13 and so on...